# How to return Response appropriately in Springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, response, httpresponse

I am returning Response in my controller using Springboot. I am throwing an Exception in my service class and returning a particular response code when the exception is caught. However, when ever I hit the endpoint on Postman I still gett `200 ok` even if an exception was caught.

Here is the service

```
public Response signup(RegisterDto register) throws CrossPointException{
        try{
            if (!register.getEmail().matches(EMAIL_PATTERN)){
                throw new CrossPointException("Email is invalid");
            }
            if(!register.getPhoneNumber().matches(PHONE_NUMBER_PATTERN)){
                throw new CrossPointException("Phone number is invalid");
            }
            Optional<User> foundUser = userRepository.findByUsername(register.getEmail());
            if(foundUser.isPresent()){
                throw new CrossPointException("Email already exist");
            }

            User user = new User();
            user.setFirstName(register.getFirstName());
            user.setLastName(register.getLastName());
            user.setPhoneNumber(register.getPhoneNumber());
            user.setEmail(register.getEmail());
            user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(register.getPassword()));
            user.setUsername(register.getEmail());
            user.setCreatedAt(new Date());
            user.setEnabled(false);
            user.setRole(Types.Role.BUSINESS);
            user.setRcNumber(register.getRcNumber());
            user.setUserType(register.getUserType());
            user.setRole(Types.Role.INDIVIDUAL);
            user.setPartnerName(register.getPartnerName());
            user.setBusinessRegistered(register.isBusinessRegistered());
            user.setGender(register.getGender());

            User savedUser = userRepository.save(user);

            basketService.createBasket(savedUser.getId());

            GenerateOtpResponseDto response =  otpService.generateOtp();
            mailService.sendMail(new NotificationEmail("Please Activate your account",
                    user.getEmail(), "this is your verification cade " + response.getOtp()));

            return Response.status(200, "testing this out").entity(BaseResponse.builder().status(true).
                    responseCode(HttpStatus.OK.toString()).message("Thanks for signing up. Kindly check your " +
                    "email to activate your account").data(user).build()).build();
        }catch (CrossPointException ex){

            return Response.status(400, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.toString()).entity(
                    BaseResponse.builder()
                            .responseCode(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.toString())
                            .status(false)
                            .message(ex.getMessage())
                            .build()
            ).build();
        }

    }
```

This is what my custom BaseResponse looks like

```
public class BaseResponse<T> {
    private boolean status;
    private String message;
    private String responseCode;
    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    private T data;
}
```

When I hit the endpoint I am getting a number of things that are needless as part of the response.

```
{
    "context": {
        "headers": {},
        "configuration": null,
        "entity": {
            "context": {
                "headers": {},
                "configuration": null,
                "entity": {
                    "status": false,
                    "message": "Email already exist",
                    "responseCode": "400 BAD_REQUEST"
                },
                "entityType": "com.crosspoint.crosspointfinance.data.model.BaseResponse",
                "entityAnnotations": [],
                "entityStream": {
                    "committed": false,
                    "closed": false
                },
                "length": -1,
                "language": null,
                "location": null,
                "mediaType": null,
                "committed": false,
                "date": null,
                "lastModified": null,
                "allowedMethods": [],
                "acceptableMediaTypes": [
                    {
                        "type": "*",
                        "subtype": "*",
                        "parameters": {},
                        "quality": 1000,
                        "wildcardType": true,
                        "wildcardSubtype": true
                    }
                ],
                "links": [],
                "entityTag": null,
                "stringHeaders": {},
                "entityClass": "com.crosspoint.crosspointfinance.data.model.BaseResponse",
                "responseCookies": {},
                "acceptableLanguages": [
                    "*"
                ],
                "requestCookies": {},
                "lengthLong": -1
            },
            "status": 400,
            "length": -1,
            "language": null,
            "location": null,
            "mediaType": null,
            "cookies": {},
            "metadata": {},
            "date": null,
            "lastModified": null,
            "allowedMethods": [],
            "entity": {
                "status": false,
                "message": "Email already exist",
                "responseCode": "400 BAD_REQUEST"
            },
            "statusInfo": {
                "reasonPhrase": "400 BAD_REQUEST",
                "statusCode": 400,
                "family": "CLIENT_ERROR"
            },
            "links": [],
            "entityTag": null,
            "stringHeaders": {},
            "headers": {}
        },
        "entityType": "org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.OutboundJaxrsResponse",
        "entityAnnotations": [],
        "entityStream": {
            "committed": false,
            "closed": false
        },
        "length": -1,
        "language": null,
        "location": null,
        "mediaType": null,
        "committed": false,
        "date": null,
        "lastModified": null,
        "allowedMethods": [],
        "acceptableMediaTypes": [
            {
                "type": "*",
                "subtype": "*",
                "parameters": {},
                "quality": 1000,
                "wildcardType": true,
                "wildcardSubtype": true
            }
        ],
        "links": [],
        "entityTag": null,
        "stringHeaders": {},
        "entityClass": "org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.OutboundJaxrsResponse",
        "responseCookies": {},
        "acceptableLanguages": [
            "*"
        ],
        "requestCookies": {},
        "lengthLong": -1
    },
    "status": 200,
    "length": -1,
    "language": null,
    "location": null,
    "mediaType": null,
    "cookies": {},
    "metadata": {},
    "date": null,
    "lastModified": null,
    "allowedMethods": [],
    "entity": {
        "context": {
            "headers": {},
            "configuration": null,
            "entity": {
                "status": false,
                "message": "Email already exist",
                "responseCode": "400 BAD_REQUEST"
            },
            "entityType": "com.crosspoint.crosspointfinance.data.model.BaseResponse",
            "entityAnnotations": [],
            "entityStream": {
                "committed": false,
                "closed": false
            },
            "length": -1,
            "language": null,
            "location": null,
            "mediaType": null,
            "committed": false,
            "date": null,
            "lastModified": null,
            "allowedMethods": [],
            "acceptableMediaTypes": [
                {
                    "type": "*",
                    "subtype": "*",
                    "parameters": {},
                    "quality": 1000,
                    "wildcardType": true,
                    "wildcardSubtype": true
                }
            ],
            "links": [],
            "entityTag": null,
            "stringHeaders": {},
            "entityClass": "com.crosspoint.crosspointfinance.data.model.BaseResponse",
            "responseCookies": {},
            "acceptableLanguages": [
                "*"
            ],
            "requestCookies": {},
            "lengthLong": -1
        },
        "status": 400,
        "length": -1,
        "language": null,
        "location": null,
        "mediaType": null,
        "cookies": {},
        "metadata": {},
        "date": null,
        "lastModified": null,
        "allowedMethods": [],
        "entity": {
            "status": false,
            "message": "Email already exist",
            "responseCode": "400 BAD_REQUEST"
        },
        "statusInfo": {
            "reasonPhrase": "400 BAD_REQUEST",
            "statusCode": 400,
            "family": "CLIENT_ERROR"
        },
        "links": [],
        "entityTag": null,
        "stringHeaders": {},
        "headers": {}
    },
    "statusInfo": "OK",
    "links": [],
    "entityTag": null,
    "stringHeaders": {},
    "headers": {}
}
```

This is response is too lengthy and contains a lot of useless info.

All I want is something like this:

```
{
    "status": true,
    "message": "Successfully Joined wait-list",
    "responseCode": "200 OK",
    "data": {
        "id": "6349a3be93a8523e3f40ee00",
        "email": "ojoi@gmail.com",
        "firstName": "Ojo"
    }
}
```

This is what my controller looks like

```
  @PostMapping("/signup")
    @PermitAll
    public Response signUp(@RequestBody RegisterDto register) throws CrossPointException{
        return Response.ok(auth.signup(register)).build();
    }
```

Comment: `Response` is an object wrapped in the **HTTP Response** body sent back to the caller.  It's the **HTTP Response**  that needs to have its status code set to BadRequest.  There are various mechanisms to do this such as @ControllerAdvice, @ExceptionHandler, global exception handler...

Comment: Can you give more details or provide a link where I can read up on this please?

Comment: [This](https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring) is a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Data
public class BaseResponse<T> {
    private final Boolean status;
    private final String message;
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    @JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateTimeDeserializer.class)
    @JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateTimeSerializer.class)
    private final LocalDateTime timeStamp;
    private final T payload;

    public BaseResponse(Boolean status, String message, T payload) {
        this.status = status;
        this.message = message;
        this.timeStamp = LocalDateTime.now();
        this.payload = payload;
    }
```

Comment: after you gonna use ResponseEntity<BaseResponse<Response>> on your controller and you will achive

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your answer. Please provide more details about your solution. Code snippets, high quality descriptions, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise answers are more helpful and easier to understand for everyone. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your answer with specifics to raise the quality of your answer. For more information: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Happy coding!